# What does it mean to say that the Turtle Armor "increases chances of being targeted by enemies"?

Tags: terraria

The tooltip for Turtle Armor says that it "[i]ncreases chances of being targeted by enemies". Can someone explain what this means? It seems to me that every enemy that spawns targets me anyway. Does it increase spawn rate, like a water candle? If you're playing single player, what (if anything) does it do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The effect makes you more likely to be targeted by enemies instead of other players in multiplayer.

Comment: ^ Like a tank with taunt of a sort. They'll come for you, assuming you'll be trying to soak up damage for your buddies.

Comment: Putrid Scent, an accessory dropped from Corruption Mimics, has the exact opposite effect - it makes enemies less likely to target you instead of other players. Note that both of these effects *only work in multiplayer* - they have no effect in singleplayer (since you're the only person enemies can target anyways).